# How to access Unread SMS in Android?

Tags: android, email, sms, jakarta-mail, android-contentresolver

I am able to read SMS in Android from this:-

```
        phonesms = new ArrayList<String>();    
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();                                                                  
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
    startManagingCursor(cur);
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cur.getCount(); i++) {
            try {
 String smsbody = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
 phonesms.add(smsbody);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

Now **Problem is that I want to access Unread SMS** & send Unread SMS automatically Through Email in a time period.

I can send sms on email from two methods:-
1. Through Intent
2.Java Mail Api

But **How to send unread sms automatically via Email within a fixed Time Period.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get unread sms:

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, "read = 0", null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can can use cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("status") to determine whether it is read or not. Or you can include them in the query itself to filter out only messages which are unread.

```
  while (cur.moveToNext()) {
               String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
               String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
        int status = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("status"));
        if(status == SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_UNREAD ) {
        //do whatever you want
        }

          }
```

Comment: Sir! SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_UNREAD gives (3) every time. & Status is -1 every time & unread=null during debugging. Where is the Problem?